# Primefaces Datatable Dialogue box issue

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces

I am using jsf 2.0 and primeface 3.5;
i am displaying a datatable and on the selection of any row, i display details in dailogue box. now the problem is when the page is loaded, and for the first time i select any row , the dialogue display nothing, but after that it works properly, what can be the reason of this issue

```
<h:body>
<h:form id="form">
    <p:dataTable var="row"
        value="#{user.list}" paginator="true"
        rows="10" selection="#{user.selectedUser}"
        filteredValue="#{user.filteredUser}" rowKey="#{row.attackID}"
        rowsPerPageTemplate="5,10,15" selectionMode="single" paginatorPosition="bottom">

        <p:ajax event="rowSelect" update=":form:display"
            oncomplete="dlg.show()" listener="#{user.selected()}"/>  

        <p:column headerText="User-ID" filterBy="#{row.userID}">
            <h:outputText value="#{row.userID}" />
        </p:column>
        <p:column headerText="Name" filterBy="#{row.userName}">
            <h:outputText value="#{row.userName}" />
        </p:column>
        <p:column headerText="Threat" filterBy="#{row.attackID}">
            <h:outputText value="#{row.attackID}" />
        </p:column>
        <p:column headerText="Rank">
            <h:outputText value="#{row.rank}" />
        </p:column>

    </p:dataTable>

    <p:dialog id="tDialog" header="Threat info" widgetVar="dlg"
        modal="true" height="250" width="300"  showEffect="explode"
        hideEffect="explode">
        <h:panelGrid id="display" columns="2" cellpadding="4">
            <h:outputText value="Attack ID:" />
            <h:outputText value="#{user.selectedUser.attackID} " />
            <h:outputText value="Name:" />
            <h:outputText value="#{user.selectedUser.attackName}" />
            <h:outputText value="Action Taken:" />
            <h:outputText value="#{user.selectedUser.actionTaken}" />
            <h:outputText value="Attack Time:" />
            <h:outputText value="#{user.selectedUser.attackTime }" />
        </h:panelGrid>
    </p:dialog>
</h:form>
</h:body>
```

Comment: Can you try `update=":form:tDialog"` instead of `update=":form:display"` ?

Comment: no that doesnt work, same issue dialog show no value on first click, after first click it works fine

Comment: what is the logic inside selected() method of user bean?